# fitSystemWindows not working in a coordinated layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have implemented a ViewPager Activity (see layout below). The problem is navigationTabBar is always hidden.

With no luck, I have tried tinkering with fitSystemWindows.

### Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabbed_main"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<com.gigamole.navigationtabbar.ntb.NavigationTabBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
    app:ntb_badge_size="12sp"
    app:ntb_badge_bg_color="#ffff0000"
    app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
    app:ntb_badge_position="right"
    app:ntb_badge_title_color="#ffffffff"
    app:ntb_badge_use_typeface="true"
    app:ntb_badged="true"
    app:ntb_animation_duration="400" />
</LinearLayout>


<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:id="@+id/create_new_button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white_add"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_post"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Create New Post"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_new_message"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Write New Message"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_insert_comment_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_upload_new_album"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Upload New Album"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**N.B.-** This topic has been discussed **link goes here**, and **here**; They all seem have not solve my problem.

### Update: Add screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqqX4.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I see you are already using the **Android Design Support Library**. Check [Build a Material Design App with the Android Design Support Library](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) out.

Comment: but it does not defile how to draw above the navigation toolbar

Comment: @ThomasScarecrowMaveric Replace **link goes here** and **here** with actual links.

Comment: It looks like the NavigationTabBar is showing but the tabs don't have any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `RelativeLayout` and put the `NavigationTabBar` inside the same `LinearLayout` as the `ViewPager`. Set the `ViewPager`s height to 0 with `layout_height="0dp"` and add a weigth of 1 with `layout_weigth="1"`. The layout should look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ....>

    <com.gigamole.navigationtabbar.ntb.NavigationTabBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        ... />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weigth="1"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this ones working. thanks although i later found out that this problem was only with CyngenMods not AOSP